# Solving extra apostrophe from php to java

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am doing a project on converting a database using sql, php and java for making a website. I have this inside my database:

```
echo's echos
sound wall
```

this is my code:

```
var places = [<?php 
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root",null, "cdcol");
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("select Name,Latitude,Longitude from food");
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($name,$lat,$lon);

  $space="
            ";
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        echo "['$name',$lat,$lon,$i,'Food',20],$space";
        $i++;   
    }
        $stmt->close();
        $mysqli->close();
    ?>];
```

and using php, I have make I've taken out the two data but it has cause the problem with the ' 
the data display before will be

```
var place = [['echo's echos', lat, lon, 13, 'Food', 20],
            ['sound wall', lat, lon, 13, 'Food', 20]];
```

which the array will be use for some purposes

Answer (score 0):

Try loading the values in php array using

[array_push](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php)

Then pass the array as json encoded format, use [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

so the assignment to place will be made as

```
var place = <?php echo json_encode($placearray); ?>
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

your result looks like JSON, so you could put all your variables into a PHP array and let `json_encode()` do the escaping for you:

```
$placesJson = array();
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    $placesJson[] = array($name, $lat, $lon, $i, 'Food', 20);
    $i++;   
}
$places = json_encode($placesJson);
```